# Django-channels Problems

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels, react-typescript

Good day, I am currently learning how to implement WebSocket with Django and I have encountered some roadblocks.

I'm using uvicorn and Django channels for my project, I am trying to implement a feature whereby I would be able to retain the previous message that I have been sent in a group chat. But this is my errors anytime I try to send messages.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/websockets/websockets_impl.py", line 247, in run_asgi
    result = await self.app(self.scope, self.asgi_receive, self.asgi_send)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/uvicorn/middleware/proxy_headers.py", line 84, in __call__
    return await self.app(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 62, in __call__
    return await application(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/routing.py", line 116, in __call__
    return await application(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 94, in app
    return await consumer(scope, receive, send)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 58, in __call__
    await await_many_dispatch(
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/utils.py", line 50, in await_many_dispatch
    await dispatch(result)
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 479, in __call__
    ret: _R = await loop.run_in_executor(
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/db.py", line 13, in thread_handler
    return super().thread_handler(loop, *args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/asgiref/sync.py", line 538, in thread_handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/consumer.py", line 125, in dispatch
    handler(message)
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/chatapp/server/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/channels/generic/websocket.py", line 59, in websocket_receive
    self.receive(text_data=message["text"])
TypeError: WebChatConsumer.receive() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text_data'
DEBUG:    = connection is CLOSED
```

This is my backend code, I try to use the JsonWebsocketConsumer so I don't have to convert my text_data using json.dumps() method and I also created the chat_message method to handle that function as well

```
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.generic.websocket import JsonWebsocketConsumer


class WebChatConsumer(JsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Constructor for WebChatConsumer.

        Initialize the 'room_name' attribute to "testserver".
        """
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.room_name = "testserver"

    def connect(self):
        """
        WebSocket connection handler.

        This method is called when a WebSocket connection is established.

        - Accepts the WebSocket connection.
        - Adds the current channel to the 'room_name' group.
        """
        self.accept()
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)(
            self.room_name,
            self.channel_name,
        )

    def receive(self, content):
        """
        WebSocket message receive handler.

        This method is called when a WebSocket message is received.

        - Sends the received message to the 'room_name' group.
        """
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_send)(
            self.room_name,
            {
                "type": "chat.message",
                "new_message": content["message"],
            },
        )

    def chat_message(self, event):
        """
        WebSocket message broadcast handler.

        This method is called when a message is broadcasted to the 'room_name' group.
        It sends the message to the connected WebSocket clients.

        Args:
            event (dict): A dictionary containing the event data.
        """
        self.send_json(event)

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        """
        WebSocket disconnection handler.

        This method is called when a WebSocket connection is closed.

        Args:
            code (int): The WebSocket close code.

        Returns:
            Response: Returns the result of the parent class's 'disconnect' method.
        """
        pass
```

And this is my frontend code

```
import { useState } from "react";
import useWebSocket from "react-use-websocket";

const socketUrl = "ws://localhost:9000/ws/test";

export const Server = () => {
  const [newMessage, setNewMessage] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState<string>("");
  const { sendJsonMessage } = useWebSocket(socketUrl, {
    onOpen: () => {
      console.log("Connected!");
    },
    onClose: () => {
      console.log("Closed!");
    },
    onError: () => {
      console.error("Error!");
    },
    onMessage: (msg) => {
      const data = JSON.parse(msg.data);
      setNewMessage((prev_msg) => [...prev_msg, data.new_message]);
    },
  });
  return (
    <div>
      {newMessage.map((msg, index) => (
        <div key={index}>
          <p>{msg}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
      <form action="">
        <label>
          Enter Message:{" "}
          <input
            type="text"
            value={message}
            onChange={(e) => setMessage(e.target.value)}
            onKeyDown={(e) => {
              if (e.key === "Enter") {
                e.preventDefault();
                sendJsonMessage({ type: "message", message });
              }
            }}
          />
        </label>
      </form>
      <button onClick={() => sendJsonMessage({ type: "message", message })}>
        Send Message
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks